# How to produce quasi duplicates in a Select

Tags: sql-server

Im working with MS SQL Server. I cannot explain it really good. I want to change my select statement such that it fills gaps that arent really in the datatable with duplicated values:

Assume following sample data:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 423 | 1 | 2 |
| 423 | 3 | 3 |

I want to fill up the missing col2 numbers which depends on the amount in col3, which would be a result like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 423 | 1 | 2 |
| 423 | 2 | 2 |
| 423 | 3 | 3 |
| 423 | 4 | 3 |
| 423 | 5 | 3 |

Its like reverse engineering a select distinct col1,col3

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [testtable](
    [col1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [col3] [smallint] NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO testtable
VALUES 
   (423, 1, 2),
   (423, 3, 3)
```

If its really complicated dont bother solving it, but maybe there is an easy way.

Comment: So what exactly is the logic you intend to use to "fill in" missing rows? I kinda see how the first row expands into 2, but I have no idea why the second row expands into 3. Why does the second row expand into three rows? Why not 10 or 100? Or just 2 like the first row?

Comment: the first row expands into 2 because col3 = 2 for this row. the second row has col3 = 3, so it will expand into 3 rows. However it will always fit such that col2 never has double values. So actually col3 is only important for the last row expansion. the other will fit such that col2 has every integer counting up from 1. So if this example had another row it would be (423, 6, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a recursive CTE is a possible solution:

```
; WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT 1 AS id, t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
   FROM testtable t
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.id + 1, r.col1, CONVERT(smallint, r.col2 + 1), r.col3
   FROM rCTE r
   WHERE r.id + 1 <= r.col3
) 
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM rCTE
```

Comment: wow this is very easy and it works, I didnt think it would be possible. Thank you